# Indexing into a list returned from find_elements() returning blank using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, web

My web scraping program so far is working, but when I try to populate my `tire_dict` variable the key is coming up empty. In my `for label in option_labels` loop, this code: `tire_sizes[i].text.strip()` is returning empty.

I've validated that the list in my `tire_sizes` variable has appropriate values by printing the text of each tire_size in debug mode before I start that for loop. I also confirmed I can print the text of each element in my tire_sizes list.

Does anyone know why this issue is occurring when my program reaches the `tire_dict` line?

My code:

```
def extract_data(url, service, output_folder, filename):
    # use selenium to open URL with chrome driver
    driver = get_driver(url, service)
    
    # wait for pop-up to appear that's contained in an <iframe> tag
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"attentive_creative")))
    
    # find and click "X" button to close pop-up
    try:
        close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "closeIconContainer")))
        close_button.click()
        driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
    except:
        print("Pop up message was not able to be dismissed.")

    # find the dropdown menu and its options
    dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='selectSizeButton']/div[1]/h2/div/span/button")
    option_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='selectSizeButton']/div[1]/h2/div/span[2]")
    options = option_container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "span")

    # loop through the options in the dropdown menu and extract data from each available tire size page
    tire_data = {}
    for option in options:
        # click the dropdown menu
        dropdown.click()

        # grab the tire sizes and option labels and store in lists
        tire_sizes = option.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-9gtu0e")
        option_labels = option.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")
        
        i = 0
        for label in option_labels:
            # click on the <label> tag
            label.click()

            # get the page source for that tire size, parse the HTML, and scrape data
            page_source = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
            tech_specs_data = scrape_tech_specs_data(soup)

            # create a new dictionary with the tire size as the key and the tech_specs_data as the value
            tire_dict = {tire_sizes[i].text.strip(): tech_specs_data}
            i += 1

            # update the tire_data dictionary with the new tire_dict
            tire_data.update(tire_dict)

    # driver.quit()

    # # convert dictionary to dataframe
    # df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tire_data, orient="index")

    # # export dataframe to excel
    # output_path = Path(output_folder, f"{filename}.xlsx")
    # df.to_excel(output_path, index=True)


def get_driver(url, service):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    service = Service(rf"{service}")
    chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    chrome_browser.get(rf"{url}")
    chrome_browser.maximize_window()

    return chrome_browser


def scrape_tech_specs_data(soup):
    # find the container holding the tech specs data
    container = soup.find("div", id="SiteProductSpecs")

    tech_specs_data = {}
    # loop through the data in the container and append columns and values to dictionary
    for elem in container.find_all("div", {"class": "css-36s67d"}):
        columns = elem.find_all("div", {"class":"css-1ojsquv"})
        values = elem.find_all("div", {"class":"css-4yq70y"})
        
        for column, value in zip(columns, values):
                tech_specs_data[column.text.strip()] = value.text.strip()

    return tech_specs_data

extract_data(url, service, output_folder, filename)
```

Comment: probably stale reference... do it before the label.click()  (You can confirm by try/catching the tire_sizes[i].text call.... check the exception if thrown)